# Facebook Share link post scrape no data

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I have a website **https://www.appmonkey.at/**

If I share a link on Facebook it contains **no data**.

I have also debugged it via the *Open Graph Object Debugger* (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/),

but I can´t find out why there is no data.

I have all OG Tags defined in my header.

```
<!-- OG -->
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" /> 
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://appmonkey.at/" /> 
    <meta property="og:title" content="App Monkey Dev. Studio | App Entwicklung Graz Austria" /> 
    <meta property="og:description" content="App Monkey™ - Development Studio ist ein Grazer Unternehmen für neue Medien- kommunikation und -produktion. Bitte einfach unser Portfolio besuchen. Wir haben bereits jahrelange Erfahrung bei der Umsetzung verschiedenster Leistungen und verwirklichen immer innovative Ideen. Für mehr Fragen bitte einfach kontaktieren."/>
    <meta property="og:locality" content="Graz"/>
    <meta property="og:country-name" content="Austria"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="App Monkey Dev. Studio"/>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="719256068141092" />
    <meta property="fb:page_id" content="1396318723916361" />
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="100003054736728" /> 
    <meta property="og:image"  content="https://appmonkey.at/img/logo.png" />
```

Can anyone help me to find my Problem?

Comment: Debugger return "Curl Error : SSL_CONNECT_ERROR error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number". Without https it fetch data so something is wrong with your ssl certificate.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have checked the SSL Certificate https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=appmonkey.at but I see no problem with it, any suggestion?